# RethinkDB: Port 8080 does not start after setting up system startup

Tags: system, startup, rethinkdb

I followed the guide on [RethinkDB Documentation](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/)

After setting up RethinkDB on system startup on Ubuntu 14.04 server, port 8080 does not start.

I checked rethinkdb log.

2015-10-29T18:28:53.207447805 0.086002s notice: Listening for administrative HTTP on 127.0.1.1, 10.17.0.6, 159.203.115.29, 10.132.204.34

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already had something listen on port 8080 but only for `127.0.0.1`, from your log, the server did listen on `127.0.1.1, 10.17.0.6, 159.203.115.29, 10.132.204.34`.

Try to check your `/etc/hosts` to see if you assign something to 127.0.1.1 and check the binding

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Once you found out the program that listen on, try to remove/stop it from binding to that.

Also, you can try to run this command directly:

```
rethinkdb --bind all
```

to ensure that RethinkDB will bind to all ips.

Comment: This is the answer. With your current configuration though, if you use one of the IPs you've listed and port `8080` it should work fine. It depends on from where you're trying to access the server.